# TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len() - neural network

Tags: python, neural-network

I'm trying to create this neural network so that it can predict long-term values, at first I want to predict future dollar values over time. I have only one input (time) and one output (dollar), I'm using this algorithm adapted to my situation but this error always appears and I don't know what the problem is with my neural network, all data is normalized

```py
from pybrain3.tools.shortcuts import buildNetwork

from pybrain3.datasets import SupervisedDataSet

from pybrain3.supervised.trainers import BackpropTrainer

ds = SupervisedDataSet(1, 1)

ds.addSample((0.01),(0.017743))

ds.addSample((0.02),(0.017277))

ds.addSample((0.03),(0.017076))

ds.addSample((0.04),(0.016889))

ds.addSample((0.05),(0.016605))

ds.addSample((0.06),(0.016189))

ds.addSample((0.07),(0.015914))

ds.addSample((0.08),(0.016123))

ds.addSample((0.09),(0.017996))

ds.addSample((0.1),(0.021729))

ds.addSample((0.11),(0.022663))

ds.addSample((0.12),(0.023944))


nn = buildNetwork(1, 4, 1, bias=True)

trainer = BackpropTrainer(nn, ds)

for i in range(50):
    print(trainer.train())

while True:
    dolar = float(input('enter the month of the equivalent year '))

    z = nn.activate((dolar))[0] * 100.0

       print(f'dolar accuracy: {str(z)}')
```

```
Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:/user/ex1/teste keras.py", line 31, in <module>
    z = nn.activate((dolar),)[0] * 100

  File "D:\user\python\venv\lib\site-packages\pybrain3\structure\networks\feedforward.py", line 20, in activate
    return super(FeedForwardNetworkComponent, self).activate(inpt)

  File "D:\user\python\venv\lib\site packages\pybrain3\structure\modules\module.py", line 104, in activate
    assert len(self.inputbuffer[self.offset]) == len(inpt), str((len(self.inputbuffer[self.offset]), len(inpt))) 

TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

Comment: Please add some text to your question. Currently it lacks a question. Also please provide full traceback.

Comment: I'm trying to create this neural network so that it can predict long-term values, at first I want to predict future dollar values over time. I have only one input (time) and one output (dollar), I'm using this algorithm adapted to my situation but this error always appears and I don't know what the problem is with my neural network, all data is normalized

Comment: Thank you ! Solved my problem

Comment: OK, I've made it an answer below. Please consider thumb up for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know this library, but it seems that `activate()` takes list or tuple as input, so try `activate((dolar,))`.